# Teaching at vs teaching to

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one is the correct sentence?
Teaching maths at BSc level.
OR 
Teaching maths to BSc level.
Edit:
Just to further clarify the situation. In my CV i need to write below job's responsibilities. Which one is the correct use 
   Teach maths at/to BSc level 
OR 
teaching maths at/to BSc level.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the " derogatory phrasing"

Comment: I would say that you have *taught* math *at* ***a university*** level. (And the first comment here makes no sense, unless it was in response to something that has since been deleted.)

Comment: Ok but i still teach maths so taught means i don't teach maths at the currently. Yap the first comment was in response to another comment that has since been deleted. Someone commented that teaching at is a derogatory phrasing.

Comment: If it's in reference to a resume item that is ongoing, then the present tense is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, teaching "at BSc level" refers to the difficulty of the curriculum being taught. Teaching "to BSc level" would seem to refer to the audience being taught. Without including a complete sentence for context, I can't tell which is more appropriate for you, or if there's even a difference.

Examples:

- The student was passing exams written at **the** BSc level.
- Dr. Stevens was having difficulty teaching basic concepts to BSc level students.

edit: Any "derogatory" sentiment coming from either of these usages would come from being "taught at". Used like this, it would be like someone throwing information at someone without regard to the learner. A person teaching that way could come across as callous, condescending, or simply unaware that the student isn't absorbing the teaching material.

edit 2: Thanks @Jason Bassford for pointing that out. I included the article in my first example without explanation. Bolded now for emphasis.

@Riaz Ud Din: You could also simply say something like "I taught BSc math" or "I taught BSc level math".

Comment: Regardless of the actual sentence, *at BSc level* would be wrong. *To BSc-level students* is fine, but, otherwise (if BSc is used), it should be *at* ***a*** (or possibly ***the***) *BSc level*.

Comment: Actually it's for a CV, just one sentence under the job's responsibilities title, I want to write that I teach maths to BSc level students.